# Issue with AngularJS tutorial step_02

Tags: node.js, angularjs

I have a problem with AngularJS tutorial step_02 on this url. 
http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02
I have installed nodejs, karma and jasmine on me Ubuntu 12.04 box and can run unit tests 
successfully. But there is issue. Tests not finished execution. There is following text on 
the screen: Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux) is idle. Console says that test is sucessfull. 
[image: Chrome screen]

Here is response from console:

```
georgi@sepulcher:~/Documents/angular-phonecat$ ./scripts/test.sh

Starting Karma Server (http://karma-runner.github.io)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
INFO [Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux)]: Connected on socket _yexf_t1tbbNjtj4p9dz
Chrome 31.0.1650 (Linux): Executed 1 of 1 SUCCESS (0.299 secs / 0.035 secs)
```

But test never end.

I would appreciate any help and idea why this happens.

Comment: Not sure what problem you're running into but I just made a video walking through how to install everything within Ubuntu so if you're really stuck with this it may help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zQNbsCTFrAA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's all right! the test is configured to run for ever. Every time you change your js files the test will run again. see the last line of the console: 1 of 1 SUCCESS. If you want your test only run once you have to change your karam.conf.js file and set singleRun:true.